# Mac - recording and playing back sequences of keystrokes

Tags: mac

I'm looking for a simple utility to allow me to record a short sequence of key strokes, and play it back by pressing a single key.

I need to process a large amount of data for work, and unfortunately can't automate the entire process.  However, I would like semi-automate as much of as it possible.  For example, I need to select a number from an excel file, open a new tab in a web browser, go to someurl.com/number, and press enter.  Right now that takes like 10 different clicks, simplifying it down to just one would save me a ton of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Automator supports recording macros. It doesn't allow editing the individual steps manually, but it recognizes items like links on websites even if their coordinates change.

For more complicated macros, you could use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/). It also supports temporary macros that can be recorded and run with keyboard shortcuts.

Support for recording AppleScripts is only (partially) implemented in very few applications like Finder and BBEdit. You can use the processes suite of System Events to interact with UI elements manually though.